# how show buttons and elements after function loaded in android

Tags: android

It might be silly question but as I am new to android development hope some one will give a right suggestion and I hope  wont get down votes for this.

I am having a webview and some textviews and buttons in my android app. First I am showing webview and continue button..

When clicking continue button, I am executing something in onClickListener from activity. In this function I am making visibility view.gone to webview and continue button and  setVisibility view.visible to one editText and OK button.

For this editText I am showing value from continue button's onClickListener.

My problem is, editText and OK button are available immediately after clicking continue button. editText value is not available.

I want to stop the view of editText and OK button until value available and then I want to show editText..

How to do this in activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Ankesh advised is right, here bit elaborated as per your need.

Put this code for your "continue" button's onClickListener,

```
continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {               
    continue.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    runner.execute();

    }
});
```

Also you need to add the following code to get the AsyncTask works..

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        // initiate your webview
        // call url in webview          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
}
}
```

This should solves your problem.

For more info, take a  look in the documentation,https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question is that after clicking continue button, you first process some task and then you want to show an edittext and ok button with the task returned value as edittext set text.

Then in that case you can initially set edittext and ok button visibility.gone().

After that you use AsyncTask class for executing your background task. In that class use override postexecution ()  and set edittext visiblility.visible and edittext.settext (result).

This way your task which runs on continue click will not block main ui thread also.

**Edited**

```
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

String responseString = "";

// Your task

return responseString
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

     Edittext.visible ()
    aTextView.setText(result);

}       

}
```

Comment: Ankesh, this is what I am looking exactly.. can you pls add a sample code so that it will be save lots of time for me as a new to this.. hope it will tiny time for you.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you with a rough idea of how it is done. Read some tutorials on AsyncTask for easy going. Sorry I could not post proper code as per your requirement as I am not at my desk.

Comment: @Ratwanska Did this helped you solving your issue?